# Laravel where in an update statement in the controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have this function in my controller which works:

```
foreach($models as $model) {
    if ($model->EindDatum < Carbon::now() && $model->email_send == 0) {
        DB::table('SSL')->where('userID', Auth::id())->update(['email_send' => 1]);
        $model->user()->first()->notify(new \App\Notifications\TaksComplete);
    }
}
```

Now I would like to change the update statement to this:

```
DB::table('SSL')->where('userID', Auth::id(), 'EindDatum' < Carbon::now())->update(['email_send' => 1]);
```

But this doesn't work.. its in my where statement but I don't know what I am doing wrong?

But this still updates all of the email_send columns in my database. even though it now should only update the ones in the past.

I dont get an error message

Comment: change where condition in seperate entity 
DB::table('SSL')->where('userID', Auth::id())->where ('EindDatum' < Carbon::now())->update(['email_send' => 1]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The where statement doesn't work like this

`->where('userID', Auth::id(), 'EindDatum' < Carbon::now())`

The problem is that the where clause doesn't know how to mach your expression.

You need to udpate your code like this

```
 DB::table('SSL')
 ->where('userID', Auth::id())
 ->where('EindDatum', '<', Carbon::now())
 ->update(['email_send' => 1]);
```

The result will be
`Where Userid = Auth::id() AND EindDatum < Carbon::now()`

Where `Auth::id()` and `Carbon::now` are replaced with the values returned from the facades.

[More about the where clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: Thank you. But now im getting this weird error: `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `SSL` set `email_send` = 1 where `userID` = 1 and `` is null)`

Comment: I've edited the post the problem was in the Carbon I used `<` instead of `,`

Comment: Not getting an error now. But now it just doesnt update in my database?

Comment: Did you add the Less than operator? I will update the code

Comment: Thank you! Accepting your answer in 3 minutes